# How to get in Rider same behaviour of extract variable as in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

When I use extract variable in IDEA I get a pop-up where I can set (up and down arrows) how much of code will be extracted as a new variable. How to get same functionality in Rider (it always selects automatically biggest chunk of code for me)?

Example how it looks in IDEA (normally I use a shortcut):

[image]

Comment: How do you do that? This pop up does not open for me. I usually highlight the code I want to export in a variable and press the combination. Then it just extracts it and I go on with my live. I also do not know this dialog from Intellij, how do you get this to open there?

Comment: For me it is "Variable..." action in Refactor -> Extract. I'll add a video showing it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported yet. Please, vote for the corresponding issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-470086.